# Trigger pod restart from inside the pod

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

So I have, what I thought was a common problem, but I can't find docs on how to solve it.

I have two apps (an api and an event queue listener) who both process data. There is a redis cache they share. Sometimes an external service will change a key's value (a timestamp) in the redis and I need to restart the apps.

Right now I do the following:

```py
if out_of_date:
    exit(0)
```

k8 terminates the pod and spins up a replacement. As spin up takes a few seconds >10s less than 30 there is a short downtime period.

I need to get rid of this downtime. My naive approach is to get kubectl to spin up a new pod before terminating the old one. (Its fine for more than one pod of the apps to be running, they are autoscaled anyway)

Alternatively, as I can have a minimum of two pods per app running, I could also try and only have one terminate at a time.

I can't make the redis modifying service change to send a request or event instead. I can't reduce spin up by much (it is already heavily optimised).
I can add another pod that would monitor the cache and trigger things if that helps.
This runs on AKS.

I can think of some convoluted ways that i might be able to implement this:

```py
if out_of_date and (not cache.get('terminating')):
    cache.set("terminating", 1, expire=30)
    exit(0)
```

But i was hoping there was a nicer solution as there can be 20 pods and htis would delay proceedings.

Comment: The cli-way would be to do a [`kubectl rollout restart ...` (`kubernetes.io`)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-restart-em-). This should also be available in your programming API. The requirement for this ot work is that the pod has a role associated that is allowed to redeploy itself and the application needs to know the name of its kubernetes deployment/stateful set.

Comment: as far as I understand the kubectl cannot be run in a pod to control other pods.

Comment: This is not true. It is possible (otherwise, things like argocd would not work; they use the kubernetes API to deploy, scale, ...). But as I said: the pod/program needs the corresponding rights so it is allowed to scale said deployment.

Comment: That might be the case, but for my application I was informed by the team administering the cluster that I could not run kubectl in the pod.

Comment: I never sad you should do it through `kubectl`, I just pointed out the way to do it through `kubectl`. for the language-specific clients, there are typically ways to achieve the same. If, however, the role is missing, then you're ouf of luck.